# SpamAssassing handles only one domain

Tags: 14.04, postfix, mail-server, spamassassin

After installing Postfix, Dovecot, SpamAssassing, Sieve and Amavis on my server (web01.mydomain.com) everything seems to be fine - spam mails addressed to e.g. stefan@mydomain.com or info@mydomain.com are tagged with ***SPAM*** in the subject and move to the mail folder SPAM.
Now I added another domain to my server and spam mails to this domain (e.g. info@seconddomain.de) are neither tagged nor moved.

/var/log/mail.log  shows

> Feb 21 03:38:14 web01 amavis[3673]: (03673-02) Passed SPAMMY
>   {RelayedOpenRelay}, [209.85.xxx.xxx]:33681 [209.85.xxx.xx] -> ,
>   Queue-ID: 6792F12042F, Message-ID: , mail_id: nHMCbZ-6iwb3, Hits:
>   999.901, size: 2727, queued_as: 6231E1204C1, dkim_sd=20120113:googlemail.com, 5741 ms

If I got it right 'Hits: 999.901' shows that it was handled, does it not?

At which place do I have to look at my configs? Wahat could be the reason for that? What information should I provide to you?

> Feb 21 13:48:35 web01 dovecot: lmtp(2861, info@seconddomain.com):
>   hO1FBCOyyVYtCwAAfyVwRw: sieve:
>   msgid=: stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:
in
/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user all domains have to be entered, not only .$mydomain:
@local_domains_acl = ( ".$mydomain", "nextdomain.de" );